# Advagg on Drupal shows multiple css and js files?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal-7

I added the [advag](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module and it seems to be combining files, but noticed this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__sqX0oV0PzZnon4-v--YUWKBX0MY_EglamExp-1FI654__IOPiOtulrIZqqAM0BdQCjTz3N2n6srsVUk6UjqwYEZ0__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__1bGi9mT6hqx9o6nD5bJXmoSMpEPHhptLYP525xD_0e0__8xO7pFjt9gkiLqNXp1T5pf1qVx1B3E4JiRdo_bonpCk__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__WYBdBM69hbZ67HwkvEm3Klcgr0gEMg-hTDrv-ofiu_0__UJzap9vYL6P5WufuIpZ4HrhEDqpuUpzKBitKuUMmMwY__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__dC61ke986faoUib_CT99MB7tZjBA8yWX9ATTkjpTWyw__Vi6qRHAK9JP9CJy6hO-AskwMgX7bln4vsoJjDBzEOnE__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__OFsSsQzSaj6v-Oy0a_SsA80EpScOeUbJnZ4cKkiFU9o__uGtSosYSD4fR0mdlliQtbwJx0EbabeubaVWqq2KIlTA__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__ZnLWb-BTdQmjePHZT3a_HE5Vg9BrAL8v6h1eu0z7Eek__4LsSbjnjVeap6QGx4vvBE7-WJQUGh3gN1gnMb0Bjh48__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__bf0eTJ6iQnY3GsZO7jbyMczh0IjbGhGwoHB8QRMrO6M__JT_BtjvKQ3w-jLHLX6W2O9rJXNxR4c_rolkuXQfBusU__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__PdS3RA9MOoQrUBcBhAkRohLUbcIwqBt3WT-iQ0WBYYM__J5JCc-DaME9iOvxgHsman1xajK_HcsQnORtLYdyva5g__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__hrgDaYfGryCYs0RZQAb5BmgzuYw72p8FV3Uo4YGA-no__Osy32LqTRLSPiyOxYFNLa9K5k3YtrwL2yGKmO4sq_74__5y1bpT1aXe8cG3wqlISSnUVr8eB3ifViQaWktQUOMrU.js"></script>
```

Why is Drupal Advag creating multiple files and not just one? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box AdvAgg will mimic what core does; you need to configure it act how you want it to. On the `admin/config/development/performance/advagg` page uncheck "Use cores grouping logic". A really good guide on how to get your site to load faster is this issue for using AdvAgg on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2493801